# Using intsvy package to calculate weighted means with PIAAC data suddenly gives error message

Tags: r, package

I have been using intsvy for over two years now, but after updating my R studio version my codes are no longer running.
Please see the following example code (using Austrian PIAAC data downloaded from OECD website):

```
data <- read.csv("https://webfs.oecd.org/piaac/puf-data/CSV/prgautp1.csv")
library(intsvy)
austria.mean <- piaac.mean.pv (pvlabel="LIT", by="CNTRYID", data=data)
```

This gives me the following error message:

```
Error in sum(sapply(seq_along(pvnames), function(i) (PV.mean[i] - MEAN.m)^2)) : 
  invalid 'type' (list) of argument
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In grep(pvnames, names(data), value = TRUE) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In mean.default(PV.mean) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
3: In mean.default(PV.sd) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
4: In mean.default(sapply(seq_along(pvnames), function(i) cc * sum((R.mean[,  :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

Here is more info on the function:
`dput(piaac.mean.pv)`

```
function (pvlabel, by, data, export = FALSE, name = "output", 
    folder = getwd()) 
{
    intsvy.mean.pv(pvnames = paste("PV", pvlabel, 1:10, sep = ""), 
        by = by, data = data, export = export, name = name, folder = folder, 
        config = piaac_conf)
}
```

The same error message occurs wehen I am using `intsvy.mean.pv`. I experience the same problem on my office computer (Windows) and my personal laptop (Mac). Would be great if someone could help! Thank you.

Session Info:

```
- Session info -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
 os       Windows 10 x64              
 system   x86_64, mingw32             
 ui       RStudio                     
 language (EN)                        
 collate  German_Germany.1252         
 ctype    German_Germany.1252         
 tz       Europe/Berlin               
 date     2021-08-18                  

- Packages ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 package      * version   date       lib source                        
 abind          1.4-5     2016-07-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)                
 assertthat     0.2.1     2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 backports      1.2.1     2020-12-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)                
 base64enc      0.1-3     2015-07-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)                
 cachem         1.0.5     2021-05-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 callr          3.7.0     2021-04-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 car            3.0-11    2021-06-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 carData        3.0-4     2020-05-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)                
 cellranger     1.1.0     2016-07-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 checkmate      2.0.0     2020-02-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 cli            3.0.1     2021-07-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 cluster        2.1.0     2019-06-19 [2] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                
 colorspace     2.0-2     2021-06-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 crayon         1.4.1     2021-02-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 curl           4.3.2     2021-06-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 data.table     1.14.0    2021-02-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 DBI            1.1.1     2021-01-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 desc           1.3.0     2021-03-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 devtools     * 2.4.2     2021-06-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 digest         0.6.27    2020-10-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 dplyr          1.0.7     2021-06-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 ellipsis       0.3.2     2021-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 fansi          0.5.0     2021-05-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 fastmap        1.1.0     2021-01-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 forcats        0.5.1     2021-01-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 foreign        0.8-80    2020-05-24 [2] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                
 Formula        1.2-4     2020-10-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)                
 fs             1.5.0     2020-07-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 generics       0.1.0     2020-10-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 ggplot2        3.3.5     2021-06-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 glue           1.4.2     2020-08-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 gridExtra      2.3       2017-09-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 gtable         0.3.0     2019-03-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 haven          2.4.3     2021-08-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 Hmisc          4.5-0     2021-02-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 hms            1.1.0     2021-05-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 htmlTable      2.2.1     2021-05-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 htmltools      0.5.1.1   2021-01-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 htmlwidgets    1.5.3     2020-12-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 intsvy       * 2.5       2021-01-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                
 jpeg           0.1-9     2021-07-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 jsonlite       1.7.2     2020-12-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 knitr          1.33      2021-04-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 lattice        0.20-41   2020-04-02 [2] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                
 latticeExtra   0.6-29    2019-12-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 lifecycle      1.0.0     2021-02-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 magrittr       2.0.1     2020-11-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 MASS           7.3-51.6  2020-04-26 [2] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                
 Matrix         1.2-18    2019-11-27 [2] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                
 memisc         0.99.27.3 2020-11-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 memoise        2.0.0     2021-01-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 munsell        0.5.0     2018-06-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 nnet           7.3-14    2020-04-26 [2] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                
 openxlsx       4.2.4     2021-06-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 PIAAC        * 1.0       2021-08-18 [1] Github (pbiecek/PIAAC@af59c23)
 pillar         1.6.2     2021-07-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 pkgbuild       1.2.0     2020-12-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 pkgconfig      2.0.3     2019-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 pkgload        1.2.1     2021-04-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 plyr           1.8.6     2020-03-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 png            0.1-7     2013-12-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)                
 prettyunits    1.1.1     2020-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 processx       3.5.2     2021-04-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 ps             1.6.0     2021-02-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 purrr          0.3.4     2020-04-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 R6             2.5.0     2020-10-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 RColorBrewer   1.1-2     2014-12-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)                
 Rcpp           1.0.7     2021-07-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 readxl         1.3.1     2019-03-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 remotes        2.4.0     2021-06-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 repr           1.1.3     2021-01-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 reshape        0.8.8     2018-10-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 rio            0.5.27    2021-06-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 rlang          0.4.11    2021-04-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 rpart          4.1-15    2019-04-12 [2] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                
 rprojroot      2.0.2     2020-11-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 rstudioapi     0.13      2020-11-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 scales         1.1.1     2020-05-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 sessioninfo    1.1.1     2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 stringi        1.7.3     2021-07-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 stringr        1.4.0     2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 survival       3.1-12    2020-04-10 [2] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                
 testthat       3.0.4     2021-07-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 tibble         3.1.3     2021-07-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 tidyselect     1.1.1     2021-04-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 usethis      * 2.0.1     2021-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 utf8           1.2.2     2021-07-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 vctrs          0.3.8     2021-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 withr          2.4.2     2021-04-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 xfun           0.25      2021-08-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                
 zip            2.2.0     2021-05-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                

[1] C:/Users/creiter/Documents/R/win-library/4.0
[2] C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.2/library
```

Comment: The error message alone is not enough for us to know what happened. Can you post the code you've tried and sample data? Please edit **the question** with the code you ran and the output of `dput(PV.mean)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(PV.mean, 20))`. And the same for other relevant data sets.

Comment: Thanks a lot @RuiBarradas. I've included the info you requested in the question. Looking forward to your help!

Comment: This seems to be a package error, try contacting `maintainer("intsvy")`.

Answer (score 0):

Package was updated by package author and all functions are working again. Thank you!